# What is the key sequence for closing the current buffer in Emacs?

Tags: emacs

If I click on menu *File* → *Close*, it closes the buffer like I want, but it doesn't list a key mapping for it. What is the key mapping?

Comment: The selected answer doesn't answer your question, the other one does.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>K</kbd> to kill the current buffer. See the [Emacs manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Kill-Buffer.html).

Comment: Since the question asks how to kill the current buffer, `kill-this-buffer`, mapped to `s-k`, is faster. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26592985/109618

Comment: This does not close the buffer. In someone's perverted mind, the buffer stays open and is filled with the contents of another buffer. What idiot is responsible for this awful ux??? How hard can it possibly be to get the buffer of interest to take up 80x24 of the terminal???

Comment: I just realize s-k => 's' => is 'super' key, LOL.. I never know what it super key before.

Comment: C-x k doesn't 'kill' (whatever that may mean) the current buffer but merely empties it. If I do C-x b after I 'killed' a buffer it is still in the list. How do I kill the buffer AND remove it from the list?

Answer (score 33):

[BKB has already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207510/what-is-the-key-sequence-for-closing-the-current-buffer-in-emacs/207514#207514) given the correct answer. I just wanted to add that `C-h b` lists the key bindings applicable in the current buffer.

Comment: C-h b is a lifesaver when you're editing a new type of file for the first time in emacs.

Comment: Unfortunately, BKB (user 27055) deleted all his answers. The answer (from Google's cache) was: "C-x k kills the current buffer C-x # kills a server buffer (if you use Emacsclient)"

Answer (score 24):

The question asks how to kill the *current* buffer. Use `M-x kill-this-buffer`. On my Emacs, it is mapped to `s-k`. Fewer keystrokes is better!

By default, 's' (for [super key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_key_(keyboard_button))) is the [Windows key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_key) on most keyboards and the [Command key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_key) on Mac.

Comment: `s-k`? As in, Shift-K, the same key that usually types the uppercase K key?

Comment: 's' as in 'super'. That maps to the Command / Apple key on OS X.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about that convention.

Comment: When made explicit, the Shift modifier is written as an upper-case `S` in Emacs' key notation. Commonly it is implicit, though (e.g. `M-%` rather than `M-S-5`, and `C-c H` rather than `C-c S-h`).

Comment: What is the equivalent of 's'/'super' key on Linux? Is there a substitute key for it?

Comment: if you are using a standard non-Mac keyboard, the super key is the "Windows" key, usually located between Ctrl and Alt

Answer (score 22):

Well, you can view the shortcut of any function with the `Help` command (<kbd>C-h</kbd>).

Press <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> and then type the command name as you would in <kbd>M-x</kbd> mode.

---

For example (in your case):

1. Press <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>w</kbd>
2. Type the name of the command: `kill-buffer` ( you can also use tab/space to autocomplete :) )
3. Press <kbd>RET</kbd>

---

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 12):

1. `C-x k` to kill the current buffer.
2. `C-x 0` to close the current window.
3. `C-x 1` to close every other window.